# Custom flutter icons

Tags: flutter, vector, icons

I just setup my project and would like to use vector icons from https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_vector_icons. After install everytime i perform a `flutter run` command i get the following error :

```
Error: unable to locate asset entry in pubspec.yaml: "fonts/AntDesign.ttf".


FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Script 'C:\SDK\flutter\packages\flutter_tools\gradle\flutter.gradle' line: 896

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildDebug'.
> Process 'command 'C:\SDK\flutter\bin\flutter.bat'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
```

my pubspec.yaml file :

```
name: nyumbarnt
description: A new Flutter project.

publish_to: 'none' # Remove this line if you wish to publish to pub.dev

version: 1.0.0+1

environment:
  sdk: ">=2.7.0 <3.0.0"

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter

  cupertino_icons: ^0.1.3
  flutter_vector_icons: ^0.2.1

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter

# The following section is specific to Flutter.
flutter:

  uses-material-design: true
```

Anyone experience this or atleast know how to get around it ? This is a blank project, i.e. the icons are the first package i added.

Comment: Can you please share your pubspec.yaml, and if possible please check once the asset path

Comment: Alright i've edited the question.

Comment: I thought the fonts are added by default. Do i have to redownload the .ttf files too?

Comment: You don't have any `assets` entry in your `pubspec.yaml` file. @JoewyLombe

Comment: You have to download `font files` to use in your project or you could use the `Google fonts` package which doesn't require you to download `.ttf` or `.otf` files. @JoewyLombe

Comment: @JoewyLombe Please follow these steps to add custom fonts https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/design/fonts

Comment: Ok so asumming i want to use 'Ionicons' Icons, i need to download the .ttf file, place it in my assets folder and then set the entry point in my pubspec file?